# What is the correct way to call this method?

Tags: c++11, bind, placeholder

I'm trying to understand `placeholders` but i can't call this method. I have an implicit parameters `Dummy{}`, `float` and `LastDummy{}`. When i call function i skip these parameters. Also my call doesn't work.

```
struct AnotherDummy {};
struct YetAnotherDummy {};
struct LastDummy {};

class X { public:
    void foo(std::string one, Dummy two, int three, AnotherDummy four, 
             float five, YetAnotherDummy six, double seven, int eight, LastDummy nine)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    auto functor = std::bind(&X::foo, _6, _3, Dummy{}, _5, _1, 5.0f, _4, _2, _7, LastDummy{});

    X obj;
    functor(&obj, YetAnotherDummy{}, 1, 2.3f, 'x', AnotherDummy{}, Dummy{}, 2.3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-static member functions the object to call the function on (what becomes the `this` pointer inside the member function) is passed as a hidden first argument.

So the major problem with the usage of `functor` is that the `X` object `obj` should be the *first* argument to the function, i.e. placeholder `_1`. The remaining arguments starts at placeholder `_2`.

So you need to do e.g.

```
auto functor = std::bind(&X::foo, _1, _7, _4, Dummy{}, _6, _2, 5.0f, _5, _3, _8, LastDummy{});
```

Note that `_1` is not the first argument to the function, and that the remaining placeholders have been increased by `1`.

Comment: Ok, but who is _2 now ?

Comment: @IonutAlexandru `_2` is the first *formal* argument (`std::string one` in your example).

Comment: I was expecting that, but what about _4 i have an implicit parameter float and _4 + 1 = _5 which is also float.

Comment: @IonutAlexandru `float five` becomes `_6` and so on. And in the `functor` argument list it's the fourth argument (because it's the fourth placement holder).